# Frames Not Shown Inside Divison

Tags: html

I am having  FrameSet like this :

```
<FRAMESET rows="80%,20%">
<FRAME SRC="displayMessages.jsp#current" name="MessageWin">
<FRAME SRC="sendMessage.jsp" name="TypeWin">
</FRAMESET>
```

Now I want a divison tag outside this FrameSet Like this :

```
<div class="right_sidebar">
<div class="mail_title"><img src="images/my_inbox.png">My Inbox</img></div>
<div class="mail_indox">
<FRAMESET rows="80%,20%">
<FRAME SRC="displayMessages.jsp#current" name="MessageWin">
<FRAME SRC="sendMessage.jsp" name="TypeWin">
</FRAMESET>
</div></div>
```

But the frames are not shown .Please help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "frame" use the iframe tag. it is working fine.

```
<iFRAME SRC="displayMessages.jsp#current" name="MessageWin">
<iFRAME SRC="sendMessage.jsp" name="TypeWin">
```

Updated jsfiddle link for your reference..

http://jsfiddle.net/3y4X2/